# Extern C functions in Objective-c

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, extern

i develop iPhone apps, and after updating to sdk 3.0, I get an error on CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL while linking. This is the code I call to get the error.

```
streamInfo.writeStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, urlRefWrite);
```

I have an idea that it can be solved using extern "C", but after having googled it, I have not found the solution to my problem. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us the error message?

Comment: I don't have 3.0 on the machine I'm on now, but right off the top of my head, are you linking with CoreServices?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was - I created a new project and copied all my classes into that project, but forgot to include the frameworks I was using. So what fixed the problem, was including them - simple as that :)

Comment: I believe that you should answer the question stating that was the problem and "accept" that answer so that this question is no longer "open". Just a thought...

Answer (score 10):

extern "C" may do the trick. I'm able to get C functions to compile and link by doing something like this both around the implementation and header file declaration. Here's a simple example:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/// converts a degree value to radians
double DegreesToRadians(double degrees);

/// converts radian value to degrees
double RadiansToDegrees(double radians);


#if __cplusplus
}   // Extern C
#endif
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "Math.h"

#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};
double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) {return radians * 180/M_PI;};


#if __cplusplus
} //Extern C
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You should never have to use `extern "C"` in an Objective-C project. This is because Objective-C is a strict superset of C.